# CSS button over google map not clickable

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm using *Google Map Javascript Api* to put a map on my website.
I created a button on the top right corner of the map just so the user could close it
This is my CSS button code:

```
#close-map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #ffc300;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 400;
}
```

I used jQuery to put it inside the #map div

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#map').prepend('<div id="close-map">close map</div>');
});
```

and I have jQuery code to hide the map when I'm clicking on it
So I can see the button on the corner but it's not clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put that clickable button out of the #map div. for that you can wrap it on another div (testing-div) and put button into it.

```
<div class="testing-div" style="position:relative;">
<div id="close-map">close map</div>
<div id="map" style="height: 580px"></div>
</div>
```

now you can add some jquery to close the testing-div

```
 $("#close-map").click(function(){
    $(".testing-div").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought about it : )

Comment: you welcome. please vote and make it checked if this answer help you :)